# SSRS data services Sharepoint 2013 xml

Tags: sharepoint, soap, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, xmldatasource

in SSRS 2016 I write the following XML data Source:
`https://<site>/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx`

and afterwards the following DataSet:

```
<Query>
 <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/GetGroupCollectionFromUser
    </SoapAction>
    <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory" 
    Name="GetGroupCollectionFromUser">
     <Parameters>
     <Parameter Name="userLoginName">
          <DefaultValue>user</DefaultValue>
     </Parameter> 
     </Parameters>
     </Method>
     <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

being **user** a `dataSetParameter=User!UserID`

launching the query in the query designer I get the following error. Help is really appreciated:

```
===================================
An error occurred while executing the query.
Failed to execute web request for the specified URL.
Soap Fault:
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder)
===================================
```

Failed to execute web request for the specified URL.

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
             <faultstring>Exception of type 
                 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was 
                  thrown.
             </faultstring><detail><errorstring 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">The parameter 
loginName cannot be empty or bigger than 251 characters.</errorstring>
<errorcode 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x80131600</errorcode>
</detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```